# SQL Server sparse columns - applying on column with existing data does not seem to save space

Tags: sql-server, sparse-matrix, sql-server-2017

We use a database with an existing model (we can't add/remove columns), and a huge amount of data. A table with millions of rows has a bunch of columns that we do not use, and are completely null. I am exploring the use of sparse column in SQL Server to reduce the amount of data stored in these columns.

I did a small POC to determine how much space would be saved.

I created a test table

```
create table sparseDataTest1 (testColumn float)
```

and inserted about 10k null records.

```
sp_spaceused N'sparseDataTest1'
```

shows that the used space is **192 KB**. I then set the test column as SPARSE using

```
alter table sparseDataTest1 
    alter column testColumn add sparse
```

I rebuilt, reorganized the indexes. However I do not see any change in the size of the data, which remains as **192 KB**.

Instead, if I try using a similar table with the column set as SPARSE during creation :

```
create table sparseDataTest2 (testColumn float sparse)
```

The used space is now **128 KB**.

I expect the used size to be the same in both tables. Am I missing something simple in terms of reorganizing data after altering sparseDataTest1?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your case. After applying **`alter table sparseDataTest1 rebuild`** size decreased.

```
create table sparseDataTest1 (testColumn float);

INSERT INTO sparseDataTest1 
SELECT TOP 10000 NULL
FROM master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2;

EXEC sp_spaceused 'sparseDataTest1';  --328 KB
alter table sparseDataTest1 alter column testColumn add sparse;
EXEC sp_spaceused 'sparseDataTest1';  --328 KB
alter table sparseDataTest1 rebuild;
EXEC sp_spaceused 'sparseDataTest1';  --264 KB

-- table 2
create table sparseDataTest2 (testColumn float sparse);

INSERT INTO sparseDataTest2 
SELECT TOP 10000 NULL
FROM master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2;

EXEC sp_spaceused 'sparseDataTest2';  --264 KB
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bd8ce721c382be31a25da26ff113795)**

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks. I was trying to rebuild using ALTER INDEX ALL ON sparseDataTest1 REBUILD